# Azure OAuth2 in Python get Access token

Tags: python, azure, oauth-2.0

I have been reading up quite a lot on Azure API and trying to get it into Python, however I can't seem to get started with it, hence I am looking for a push in the right direction.

I have a certificate and key.
I also have;

```
tenant: xxxxxx
resource: https://link.net
client_id: xxxxx
```

I have been reading on [Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)
to get it to work. When I tried something similar to chapter [Request an access token with a certificate credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token-with-a-certificate-credential) it says it also needs a required code and grant type.

Further up in the documentation I found chapter [Request an authorization code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) but it seems like I am missing the scope.

Would really appreciate any help in getting further in this question.

Comment: What do you mean you state you're reading up on Azure API? Do you mean an API app running on an App Service, API management or maybe something completely different? And when you're getting a token, what service are you getting a token for? As seen in the example, you need to specify a scope for which you would like a token.

Comment: Sorry, not used to APIs with certs and keys, more used to curl and using APIs in php and python. Got another link as https://anotherlink.host.com/func/tion/v2/function/id4
which is supposed to answer TRUE or FALSE in json format.

Comment: Not entirely sure how, but after reading your comment I now have more questions, not less... Could you clarify the points from my pervious comment?

Comment: Mainly a python-script or php-function called from a web form.
When called, I want to check on anotherlink.host.com/func/tion/v2/function/id4 if id4 is true or  false.

Am I able to use Oauth2 from Azure in python or PHP ?

Comment: Does the application on `anotherlink.host.com` actually use Azure AD authentication? If so, they should provide you with possible scopes. If not, just call the API.

Comment: After some digging I got this:
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/[SOME NUMBERS]/oauth2/authorize?response_type=id_token
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2FLINK%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Faad%2Fcallback
&client_id=MY-CLIENT-ID
&scope=openid+profile+email
&response_mode=form_post
&nonce=SOME-OTHER-NUMBERS
&state=redir%3D%252Fv4%252Ffunction%252Fid4`